# Get existing IaaSDiagnostics on Azure-Vm Scale Set

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set

Trying to find what is the existing IaaSDiagnostics on Scale Set, but not able to extract the Settings as String output,

Tried this but not much helpful as returns in JProperty form,

```
Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName usptenant-DAT-EastUS -VMScaleSetName besfvm `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty VirtualMachineProfile `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty ExtensionProfile `
| %{  $_.Extensions[1] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Settings }
```

i am stuck with Type casting or completely in wrong direction on accessing diagnostics information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a Way with Azure-Cli

Use

```
az vmss extension show --name
                       --resource-group
                       --vmss-name
```

And export the out to Json File, Make Sure that you set the extension to Json for file output , you will get Base64 Encoded String.

Edit :

With powerShell

```
(Get-AzureServiceAvailableExtension -ExtensionName 'PaaSDiagnostics' -ProviderNamespace 'Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics').PublicConfigurationSchema | Out-File –Encoding utf8 -FilePath 'C:\temp\WadConfig.xsd'
```